# Are there any performance issues with inlining CSS rather than using "chunks"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frameworks

Modern frameworks like Vue and React start with inline  CSS inside individual components. For example, in a Vue single file component, we include all the Javascript, HTML, and CSS in one `.vue` file. There is usually a build step or some computation which compiles these changes into chunks, which are loaded into the page based on what components are visible to the user.

I can appreciate that this may be the most efficient way to compile CSS for multiple components and load it into a page.

My question relates primarily to performance. Suppose instead of compiling all of the component styles into chunks, React or Vue did sent this instead, when a component is rendered:

```html
<div id="someComponent">
    <!-- My component HTML goes here -->
</div>
<style>
     /* Associated styles */
     #someComponent {
         color: red;
     }
</style>
```

That means instead of having a CSS chunk file, the styles are simply inlined and included beside the component they relate to on the live website.

I know this **is** messy, but my question is, **are there any performance concerns with doing this?** I would've thought this might actually be more performant, since loading a chunk requires an HTTP request, which obviously has an overhead, whereas this is included in a single HTTP request when the user opens the webpage.

Comment: What you are referring to as "inline" is not what inline styles actually are. This is an inline style: `<span style="color:red;">....`. Your example is of an embedded stylesheet. And any performance impact is negligible.

Comment: OK, regardless, HTTP requests are not negligible if you are doing a bunch of them like most modern frameworks do. They can add up to be quite a substantial performance hit.

Comment: Embedded stylesheets don't make additional HTTP calls - - they are "embedded" with the HTML document.

Comment: I know - I'm not sure if you've misread my question but I'm asking why don't they embed them? Because most frameworks use chunks for component CSS, which are included with <link> tags, which do have HTTP requests. If it's just because it's messy to add CSS directly to the page, then fine, but I'm wondering what the downsides are and if there are performance issues from embedding because of how chrome and other browsers load and process CSS.

Comment: External stylesheets do cause additional HTTP requests, but their impact on overall performance is generally negligible, especially considering the fact that they eliminate the need for redundant coding and testing.

Comment: It's really not negligible. If you have worked to optimize a complex website's loading time you would know that. HTTP overhead is can be significant which is why page speed tests including Google's speed test recommend limiting HTTP requests to a bare minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, although I wasn't able to do very extensive testing, there does seem to be some performance issues taking this approach. Also it leads to layout shifts (CLS) since the CSS is loaded at different times.

Good to avoid doing in general, as it seems to bring no discernible benefits. The approach I finally went with was to regex out all the inline component CSS and combine it into one large inline chunk of CSS, which cut out the HTTP request.